# OS X leopard terminal bash color

Tags: macos, colors, terminal

I work a lot in terminal on os x. I usually have two tabs opened - bash and svn on a remote server. Since files on my remote server are the same as on my disk it sometime get me confused.

Is there a chance of changing bash terminal color to ie. blue and leaving all ssh connection  in another tab in black color? I mean permanently, not just via inspector for one session.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I´d suggest using different coloured Prompts for that, this site from IBM is a good starting point for info on that topic: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/

I personally have the following line in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PS1='\[\e[44m\] \u @ \H | \[\e[7m\] $PWD \[\e[0m\] \n > \[\e[0m\] '
```

which not only colours my prompt blue, but also shows my current Hostname and which directory I´m currently in. If you have sufficient access to the other servers you use, you could give the prompt a different colour there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not what you are looking for, but just in case... I have two custom settings in the Terminal, one named "LOCAL" and another "SSH mymachinename", with completely different color settings (back/green, white/black) to help me know where I am.

I also changed the default Title of the tab/window for each setting, and on the SSH setting, in the "Shell" tab I put "ssh root@..." as a command to run on startup (I work almost exclusively on one remote machine, but you could duplicate this for more machines of course).

If you right-click the Terminal icon on the Dock you can directly open a Terminal with the appropriate settings for the session.

Also, I use Spaces (Desktops) and open the terminal for the SSH session on, say, Space 4, and the Local terminal on Space 3.